# XBOX Game bar app incorrect VRAM usage/availability

Tags: windows-10, integrated-graphics, windows-store-app, intel-core-i5, vram

[image: Screenshot]

XBOX game bar app in my windows 10 system is showing incorrect VRAM Availability and Usage for the Intel UHD 630 Integrated GPU, even though it is working fine. Task manager shows 0.3/7.9 GB as usual. My Config:

i5 9600K, MSI Gaming Motherboard
How do I fix this, Also Is this the Right stack exchange to ask this.

[image: Task manager]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you are seeing is a feature of an integrated GPU. You system lacks "dedicated" GPU VRAM and hence cannot display a number for something it doesn't have. The Intel GPU uses system RAM to work rather than having its own memory set aside for it.

My system with 8GB of dedicated VRAM shows

[image]

and

[image]

While another system with Intel Iris Plus GPU shows the same 0GB as you see.

So there are two options:

1. Intel drivers simply do not report VRAM usage
2. Having no **dedicated** VRAM the Intel drivers have nothing to actually report.

Shared memory is not actual **real** VRAM. It is your system RAM being repurposed for use by the GPU.